# Read from an external bluetooth keyboard without UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I need to read text from an external bluetooth keyboard (an Inateck barcode scanner) on iOS. I'm searching for a solution without using an hidden UITextField like a listener ?

Comment: Of what type the barcode scanner is (I mean, which brand)

Comment: I need a similar input (proximity card reader) and also didn't want to use an input field as it interferes with the on-screen keyboard for other input.  In my case I ended up having to build my own BLE device.  For barcode scanning there may be devices out there that are MFi compatible using the legacy SPP rather than the keyboard/HID profile

Comment: @KarloA.López Inateck Bluetooth

Comment: @Paulw11 Yep it's could be a solution but this app will be on 20 iPhones so I need to build 20 BLE Devices. Moreover I can't change the scanner, it's for a marathon and the association already have scanners. Thanks anyway

Comment: If it is a keyboard emulation device then a UITextField is your only option

Comment: @Paulw11 yes it is. Ok I hoped a way to catch keyboard inputs like KeyBindings on OSX. If it's your answer write it I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no lower-level API to intercept keystrokes on iOS.  If your barcode scanner emulates a keyboard (HID Profile) then your only option is to pair it as a keyboard and direct input into a UITextField.  This text field can be hidden as you point out.

Comment: But the issue is, that the TF needs to be focused and for that, the iPad Keyboard is visible.

Comment: The iPad keyboard should be hidden when a hardware keyboard is connected. As I said in my answer, keyboard emulating barcode scanners are not a good solution for iOS. Scanners with their own BLE api are better

Comment: But it looks like Tuan's answer might be a better solution than my 8 year old one

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with an external keyboard (although read text from BUSICOM Desktop 1D/2D/QR Code Reader through a cable instead of Bluetooth).

My solution is to implement `UIKeyInput` for the `UIViewController`.

**Swift 5.1**:

```
// MARK: - UIKeyInput
let keyboardHiderView = UIView()
extension QRScannerViewController: UIKeyInput {
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { true }
    var hasText: Bool { false }

    override var inputView: UIView? {
        return keyboardHiderView
    }

    func insertText(_ text: String) {
        // Character by character input in here
    }

    func deleteBackward() {}
}
```

Hoping to help someone.

Comment: This just saved my day. Actually, I don't know how many :). Really appreciate the simplest of approaches. Though I had to implement it on flutter which required a bit of work, but the essence was this lovely piece.

Comment: @malik_cesur I guess this could be at least partial remedy for raw key board events not implemented for iOS in Flutter am I right? If so I actually need something like that implemented in Flutter. Would you be in a position to share your code?

Comment: @hincar sure, actually this alone was not enough for capturing events. For iOS above 13.4, you need to listen to press events as well. I'll share the whole code for the VC I implemented. I also changed the FlutterVC with the VC I created and extended the original one. If you need further help, just mention me here. I'll go for a PR for the `RawKeyboard` component to better support iOS on the engine level once I had enough time. Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/umutyusuf/543abc9efb882e0f690aeddbf20fe796